# How can I put a product_list and a product_view on the same page?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want customers to choose among a bunch of product options, then present them with like an upsell. But that upsell is a configurable product and I want some rather complex response based on what the customer chooses.

Anyway, I created a custom module and either the product_list works or the product_view work, but they do not work together. I have tried a view different ways, but I can't get around rendering the layout in my controller.

This works for the product_list:

```
public function indexAction(){
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And this works for the product_view:

```
public function indexAction(){
  $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');
  $viewHelper->prepareAndRender(8, $this); // my product_id = 8
}
```

I feel like I'm way off on a good approach. Please help! I could not find anyone else trying to combine both these things into a single page, so any parrallel example is helpful, too.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish. You want a product view with a product list below it?

Comment: Try to copy the code from the handle catalog_product_view in the catalog.xml layout file. Then add to `content` a product_list. If you made this, copy your code here, describe what doesn't work.